# Why do people say "Work like a dog?"

Tags: meaning, idioms

To mean working hard?

Dogs just lie around and nap. That's not working hard...

Comment: It's been a hard day's night. I've been working like a dog. I should be eating like a hog. I should be sleeping like a log.

Comment: As far as I know, dogs just lie around and nap because they work like dogs all day

Comment: When it comes to just lying around and napping, dogs aren't even in the running. Bad idiom there - actually dogs are the ones energetically running around, while **cats** stick to the important things, such as lying around and napping.

Comment: In addition to the herding dogs explanation, could it also come from [Turnspit dogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnspit_Dog), which were bred to spend their day running on a wheel?  (sorry, I don't have enough reputation to create an answer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

["Sheepdogs"](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/18/messages/366.html) are definitely a reason. This [link here](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/18/messages/366.html),  also offers another explanation:

> In olden days, the two sawyers who worked on a tree sawing planks were the top-dog and the under-dog. *A dog in those days was a manual worker.* (Emphasis mine)

Perhaps the expression could also have come from a comparison with a "manual worker".

Comment: Those two links are actually the same link. :)

Comment: The "top-dog / underdog" sense sounds pretty convincing to me.  Notice that we never say "it's a hound's life" or "work like a hound", even though hound is the "original" word for dog, but we **do** say "work like a slave".

Answer (score 7):

I believe the term comes from [herding dogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herding_dog).  I'm not a farmer, but from what I hear they work their little canine tails off to help with the herding.